# Install a second copy of Hadoop in the same cluster?

Tags: hadoop

We have a cluster for dev and research with 3 nodes where hadoop 1.* was installed by somebody else. I am thinking of removing one of the data node from the earlier version hadoop and install hadoop 2.* and use it as name node. Also I want to share the 2nd data node with the hadoop 1.*.

I wonder if it's doable and is there any potential problems. Thanks a million for your advice!

Correction: I want to share a data node with another name node.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get to the level of sharing you are talking about. But you can take a look at [apache mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/) to install multiple clusters on the same pool of machines

Comment: Can you please explain why it will not work? Thank you!

Comment: as far as I know a namenode cannot serve 2 clusters simultaneously

Comment: Sorry, I meant sharing one of the data node with another name node. So I want to create a name node using a removed data node. and then use an existing data node as my second data node. Thanks Arnon for your help!

Comment: I am not sure it is exactly what you want but you can get a similar effect with Hadoop federation https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html